# Good models to separate speech and noise?

Tags: speech-processing, source-separation

I have an audio clip containing speech and noise. I want to separate the noise signal from the speech signal.

I've looked at some deep-learning based models, but they only remove the noise, without giving me the noise signal. I've also tried Facebook's Demucs, which performs well on music source separation but fails to separate speech and noise.

Someone told me that there are two ways to get both the clean speech and noise. One is to use a model to remove the noise and get the clean speech, and then subtract the clean speech signal from the noisy signal to get the noise signal. The other is to train a model that estimates both clean speech and noise, for which it is very hard to achieve good results.

I wonder if there are some (open source) models that can perform this task. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of noise are we dealing with here? I'm assuming since you're looking into deep learning methods that the frequency content of the noise overlaps with that of the speech. "I've looked at some deep-learning based models, but they only remove the noise, without giving me the noise signal": if you have both noisy speech and clean speech it's just a matter of substracting one from the other to get the noise, as you stated later. Speech enhancement is a very well documented field, I'm sure there are some open source models out there with a simple google search (include the term "github")

Comment: Thanks! I just tried the "subtracting method" using a SOTA model (CleanUNet by NVIDIA) and I get the noise signal, which is what I want.

Comment: Great! you answered your own question then ;)